# making an Imageview inside a method

Tags: android

I am a beginner in android development and I am trying to develop a simple solitaire game.

As I am sure you know in solitaire you have seven rows of cards and I'm trying to make them using a `FrameLayout` for each row and for every card make an `ImageView` to hold my card img and to "bind" the card object to it and I'm trying to do this with a method but I can't make a new 'ImageView' for each card. Here is the code for the method I tried to do.

```
public void addcard (card c, FrameLayout FL){
    int counter = 0;

    ImageView cardplace = new ImageView(this);

    c.setImgview(cardplace);

    FL.addView(cardplace);
    FL.addView(c.getImgview());

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams LP = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    LP.setMargins(0, (80 * counter), 0, 0);

    c.getImgview().setLayoutParams(LP);
    c.getImgview().setImageResource(c.getImg());

    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add image view like this in your method ...

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.imageLayout);
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
    image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(80,60));
    image.setMaxHeight(10);
    image.setMaxWidth(10);

    // Adds the view to the Linerlayout
    layout.addView(image);
}
```